# Flymake config error while opening python file but correctly setup flake

Tags: flake8, elpy

When I'm opening a python file in emacs I get the following error message:

> Flymake: Configuration error has occured while running (flake8 >..../xyz_flymake.py). Flymake will be switched OFF.

But on the other hand it seems I've configured all the modules needed for elpy to work properly:

```
Elpy Configuration

Virtualenv........: None
RPC Python........: 3.5.3 (/usr/bin/python3.5)
Interactive Python: /usr/bin/python3.5 (/usr/bin/python3.5)
Emacs.............: 24.5.1
Elpy..............: 1.10.0
Jedi..............: 0.10.2
Rope..............: 0.10.5
Importmagic.......: 0.1.7
Autopep8..........: 0.1.7
Syntax checker....: flake8 (/usr/local/bin/flake8)

You have not activated a virtual env. While Elpy supports this, it is
often a good idea to work inside a virtual env. You can use M-x
pyvenv-activate or M-x pyvenv-workon to activate a virtual env.

The directory ~/.local/bin/ is not in your PATH. As there is no active
virtualenv, installing Python packages locally will place executables
in that directory, so Emacs won't find them. If you are missing some
commands, do add this directory to your PATH.

Options

`Raised' text indicates buttons; type RET or click mouse-1 on a button
to invoke its action.  Invoke [+] to expand a group, and [-] to
collapse an expanded group.  Invoke the [Group], [Face], and [Option]
buttons below to edit that item in another window.
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unclear what the configuration error is. It's possible that you're running into one of many issues.

1. You seem to want to use Python 3.5, but there's no clear indicator of what version of Python Flake8 is running on. It could be that elpy is detecting a mismatch and refusing to use Flake8 when it won't provide you any useful information. (Flake8 must be installed on the same version of Python that the code is intended to run on.)
2. Elpy seems insistent that you use a virtualenv or that you add `~/.local/bin/` to your `PATH`. I would advise doing both.

   You can create a virtualenv by doing `virtualenv ~/.elpy-venv` and activate it with `source ~/.elpy-venv/bin/activate`.

   You can edit your Shell's configuration file (e.g., `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.zshrc`, etc.) to do `export PATH="$PATH:~/.local/bin"`.